# window.openDialog does not remove the titlebar on linux

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul

I use the following code to display a popup:

```
    var win = window.openDialog("chrome://broceliand/content/view/popup/nameMapPopup.xul", 
      "", 
            "all=no," +
      "titlebar=no," + 
            "chrome=yes," +
            "toolbar=no," +
            "dialog=no," +
            "resizable=no," + 
            "modal=yes," +
            "dependent=yes," +
            "top="+popupY+"px," +
            "left="+popupX+"px",
            args);
```

On windows the popup is pretty clean. There are no common elements remaining.
But on linux le [titlebar](https://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/210/=FirefoxChromeToolbarsDescription7a.gif) still remains and the popup is resizable.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `hidechrome` attribute on the `window` element to `true`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xul/window

Answer (score 0):

That might be because on Linux the window decorator is responsible for the titlebar. This can even be a seperate program to the window manager.

Does the popup need to be as a seperate window? Perhaps [panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/panel) is really what you are looking for.

Comment: Indeed panel looks great but I have to keep my code runnable on Firefox 2. I guess panel is Firefox 3 limited, isn't it ?

Comment: No. When the linked article says "This article covers features introduced in Firefox 3" it means only those attributes/properties which is tagged with "New in Firefox 3".